# How to display alert when two text field are some text

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I have two UITextField. I want to check UITextField, if two UITextField are some text show alert or if only one UITextField has some text then go forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if([txt1.text length] > 0 && [txt2.text length]>0)
    {   
        UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"TextFied Have an Text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alert show];   
    }
else
   {
        //Go Forword
   }
```

Try this code

Comment: I want go forward when only one text field has some text in that two text fields

Comment: @JitendraDeore what if there is a space in textfield??? should it show alert???

Answer (score 1):

you can use two delegate function of UITextFieldDelegate

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if ([self.textField1.text isEqualToString:self.textField2.text])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                    message:@"text field have same text"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `UITextField`'s delegate method like this...

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField1.text length] > 0 && [textField2.text length] > 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Hello" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
   else 
   {
                // go forward here.....
   }
}
```

Comment: I want go forward when only one text field has some text in that two text fields

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary - what if there is a space in textfield??? should it show alert???

Answer (score 0):

Show alert if both textField have same text, like confirm password.

```
if ([firstTextField.text isEqualToString:secodTextField.text])
    {
        //Show Alert
        return;
    }
```

Comment: he doesen't want same text in both textfield...

Comment: @JitendraDeore if two UITextField are some text??????

Comment: requirement is if the both textfield contains a tesxt shows alert then otherwise go forword...

Comment: @JitendraDeore ok buddy i edited my answer.. it will help for others..

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete code for your requirement.

```
// check if any text field has some text.
if ([txt1.text length] > 0 && [txt1.text length] > 0 )
{
   // show alert 
   UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"TextFied Have an Text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show]; 
}
// check if any one text field has some text
else if(([txt1.text length] > 0 && [txt2.text isEqualToString:@"") || ([txt2.text length] > 0 && [txt1.text isEqualToString:@"") )
{   
   // go forward  
}
```

Thats It.

Answer (score 0):

if you like to omit spaces in textfield can use following code

```
if([[self.testfield1.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] > 0 && [[self.testfield2.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length]>0)
    {
        UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"TextFields Have an Text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"TextField not having an Text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }
```